# Parsing XML key pairs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, key

Hello i need a way to parse XML that i have gotten from a PHP page and return only the keys. Here is the XML example

```
["Hello:123" , "Bye:456"]
```

I need a way to parse this so i can access the keys
["Hello","Bye"]

JS or Jquery preferred

Comment: Where is the xml? You shared an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform each element using array map. For each string, split it by ':' and take the first part:

```js
var data = ["Hello:123" , "Bye:456"];
data = data.map(str => str.split(':')[0]);
console.log(data);
```

EDIT: You can transform each string to object so you get an array of object:

```js
var data = ["Hello:123" , "Bye:456"];
data = data.map(str => {
    var [key, value] = str.split(':');
    return { [key]: value };
});
console.log(data[0].Hello);
```

And in case you want to access the second part by the first part as a key, it's good to transform to an object instead of an array:

```js
var data = ["Hello:123" , "Bye:456"];
var obj = {}, key;
data.forEach(str => {
    [key, obj[key]] = str.split(':');
});
console.log(obj.Hello);  // acess directly what comes after Hello
console.log(obj.Bye);    // acess directly what comes after Bye
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: How can i access the keys value directly. For example how can i acess directly what comes after Hello?

Comment: Getting undefined in the console log when i try and execute

Comment: And be sure propety name Hello, Bye you're typing are correct